# how to access url pathname from react server component in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I saw this and was a bit confused:

```
          <Route exact path={`/`}>
            <Redirect to={`${path}/user/:userId/pages/:pageId`} />
          </Route>
```

since I'm not exactly sure where it would get values for pageId and userId.

```
          <Route exact path={`/`}>
            <Redirect to={`${path}/user/{userId}/pages/{pageId}`} />
          </Route>
```

would make more sense to me.

The main question though is how I can convert this into a nextjs logic

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function DashboardLayout({
  children,
request
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  request: NextRequest
}) {
  const {userId, pageId} = getStuff();
  if (request.url === "") {
    redirect(`${request.url}/user/{userId}/pages//{pageId}`);
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

apparently, request doesn't exist here as a prop. I also saw this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704 so I'm trying to get around this issue. Thank you.